# U-Boot: How to evaluate one environment variable inside another

Tags: shell, embedded, environment-variables, bootloader, u-boot

In U-Boot I have these two environment variables:

```
filepath=myimages
kernelfile=${filepath}/uImage.bin
```

When I run this command:

```
echo ${kernelfile}
```

I get this output:

```
${filepath}/uImage.bin
```

However, I want it to instead evaluate the filepath variable like this:

```
myimages/uImage.bin
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it stands this cannot be accomplished with the u-boot `echo` and shell right now.  This is because the macro replacement you see with `echo` is being performed by the u-boot command line interpreter before the `echo` command has been launched.  All the echo command does is basically print the array of strings passed to it.

Specifically, if you look at `common/cli_simple.c` from the current (7/29/15) git repository of u-boot, you will find the function `cli_simple_run_command`.  This function is passed a string `cmd` that could contain multiple commands separated by `;`.  If you look inside the loop splitting this string you will find `cli_simple_process_macros` and after that you find a call to `cli_simple_parse_line` followed by `cmd_process`.  Skipping `cli_simple_process_macros` for now, `cli_simple_parse_line` basically takes a string and splits into an array of strings similar to how a shell would, giving you an `argv` and `argc` that it passes to `cmd_process` which executes the command that is in `argv[0]`.

The interesting part is `cli_simple_process_macros`.  This takes an input string as the first argument and output string as the second.  This function is a simple state machine that looks for u-boot environment variables (or macros as the function name suggests) and replaces them with the value of the environment variable.  This is seen with the call to `getenv` and then the copy to the output string.  If you look at how `cli_simple_process_macros` works you will notice that it only does one pass, that is if an environment variable contains another environment variable it does not process the second environment variable, instead it just copies the string value.

Finally, if you look at the source for the `echo` command you will see that it is very simple, just basically looping through the `argv` passed to it and printing each string with the appropriate spaces.

So basically, if you want the desired behavior, you will need to either change `cli_simple_process_macros` to be iterative for environment variables or change `echo` to look up environment variables.  You could also perhaps change `cli_simple_run_command` to invoke `cli_simple_process_macros` multiple times so that all nested environment variables are expanded.

Answer (score 7):

Or as a lazy way you could do something like this:

```
filepath=myimages
set_kernelfile= setenv kernelfile ${filepath}/uImage.bin
```

then do:

```
run set_kernelfile; echo ${kernelfile}
```